# Using Parseval's Identity to Calculate an Integral

Tags: fourier-series, parsevals-identity

The exercise is to use Parseval's identity to solve the following integral:
\begin{equation} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}e^{inx}|^2 dx
\end{equation}

Now, I know that the Parseval's identity tells us that:
\begin{equation} \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)|^2 dx = \frac{|a_0|^2}{2}+  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(|a_n|^2 + |b_n|^2)
\end{equation}

I have seen a lot of examples here evaluating integrals but my problem is that the *integral* **and** the *sum* is on the same side in my equation. How do you solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}e^{inx}$ is a geometric series.

Comment: Let $f(x) = \sum 2^{-n}e^{inx}$. What are its Fourier coefficients?

Comment: Try using Parseval in complex form and noticing that the function you are integrating is already a Fourier series

Comment: @RaulFernandesHorta , I don't see how, given that I sum from n=1 to infinity. 

My problem is that this example does not look like any example I've done so far. I don't know from where to attack this problem.

Comment: @kieransquared , Should I find Fourier coefficients of a sum?

Answer (score 1):

let
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}e^{inx} = \sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}(\cos(nx) + i\sin(nx)).
$$
Hence
$$
a_0 = 0,\quad a_n = \frac{1}{2^n},\quad b_n = \frac{i}{2^n}\quad (n = 1,2,\cdots).
$$
From the Parseval's identity, we got
$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left|f(x)\right| = \pi \sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \frac{2}{2^{2n}} = \frac{2\pi}{3}.
$$

Comment: Sorry, how exactly was the last step made? From the $2^{2n}$ I think you squared something but not the whole expression? And where does $\pi$ come from?

Comment: The second to last equality is Parseval’s identity; plug in $a_n$ and $b_n$ and move $\pi$ over to the other side and you should get the same expression. The last equality is from the sum of a geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^n = 1/(1-a)$ for $|a|<1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you a hint:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}e^{inx}$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{e^{ix}}{2}\right)^n$$
$$=\dfrac{\dfrac{e^{ix}}{2}}{1-\dfrac{e^{ix}}{2}}$$

which means $$|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}e^{inx}|^2 = \dfrac{1}{2-2\cos x}=\dfrac{1}{4\sin^2(\dfrac{x}{2})}=\left(\frac{\csc(\dfrac{x}{2})}{2}\right)^2$$

So your $f(x)$ is $\dfrac{1}{2}\csc(\dfrac{x}{2})$.

The Fourier expansion can now be done and you can use Parseval's identity. However, you can also directly compute the integral using substitution, but that might be a bit complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think there has to be a much more simple way to solve this. This is absolutely over my lvl right now.